# Regular expression for hidden files under unix

Tags: regex, cmake

I'm looking for a regex to match every file begining with a "." in a directory.

I'm using CMake (from CMake doc : "CMake expects regular expressions, not globs") and want to ignore every file begining with a dot (hidden files) BUT `"\..*"` or `"^\..*"` doesn't work :(

The strange thing : this works (thanks to rq's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727075/regular-expression-for-hidden-files-under-unix/729082#729082)) and remove every hidden files and temp files ("~" terminated files)

```
file(GLOB DOT ".*")
file(GLOB TILD "*~")

set (CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES "${DOT};${TILD}")
```

But I can't find the right thing to write directly into `CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES` to have the same result!

Here is the  "[doc](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:CPackConfiguration)" of this variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like GLOB is probably what you want.

Try this. Open a file "test.cmake" and add the following:

```
file(GLOB ALL "*")
file(GLOB DOT ".*")
file(GLOB NOTDOT "[^.]*")

message("All Files ${ALL}")
message("Dot files ${DOT}")
message("Not dot files ${NOTDOT}")
```

Then create a couple of test files:

```
touch .dotfile
touch notdot
```

Then run "cmake -P test.cmake". The output is:

```
All Files /tmp/cmake_test/.dotfile;/tmp/cmake_test/notdot;/tmp/cmake_test/test.cmake
Dot files /tmp/cmake_test/.dotfile
Not dot files /tmp/cmake_test/notdot;/tmp/cmake_test/test.cmake
```

This was tested with cmake 2.6.0.

Comment: Even if "CMake expects regular expressions, not globs", your solution help me do what I want using CMake variables to list all files I want to ignore. What is weird : I can't find the right thing to write directly into the variable in order to avoid listing the file using your solution. Thx anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Using standard regex syntax:

```
^\..*
```

Since CMake apparently doesn't like this, it may use something like:

```
^\\..*
```

That's just a guess, though, since I don't have/use CMake.

Comment: I need a regex to use in CMake, your expression gives me the result : "CMake Error: Invalid escape sequence \."

Comment: maybe you nead to add slashes /^\..*/

Comment: CMake is doing you wrong, then. That's the standard regex syntax to do what you asked. Maybe it requires you to use ^\\..* instead?

Comment: *"a guess, though, since I don't have/use CMake."* That seems equivalent to "not useful" - in my case, also a waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

The following one-liner will do the work (hide hidden and tilde ("~") terminated files):

```
set(CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES "/\\\\..*$;~$;${CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape it.

```
^\..*
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^[.].*
```