# cmake find hidden files

Tags: regex, linux, cmake

In my `CMakeLists.txt` I am trying to find hidden files like `.git` to exclude from further actions:

```
if(${item} MATCHES "\.*")
```

Didn't work for me. Any hints please?

Comment: What is the `item` in the code you show? And what "Didn't work" *actually* means? Note, that regex `\.*` means "dot character repeated zero or more times."

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/727082/805896) worked for me:

```
if(${item} MATCHES "^\\..*")
```